# C++ Memory Error

Tags: c++, memory, reference

When I compile my code, I repeatedly get the error

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

Yet the code only goes so far as to create references. Specifically, commenting out a specific line seems to fix the error; however, it's a very important line.

```
void neuron::updateWeights(layer &prevLayer) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < prevLayer.size(); i++) {
        double oldDeltaWeight = prevLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_deltaWeight;
        double newDeltaWeight = eta * prevLayer[i].m_output * m_gradient + alpha * oldDeltaWeight;
        prevLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_deltaWeight = newDeltaWeight; // THIS LINE
        prevLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_weight += newDeltaWeight; 
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

EDIT:
Additional code
// Headers
    #include "../../Include/neuralNet.h"

```
// Libraries
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// Namespace
using namespace std;

// Class constructor
neuron::neuron(unsigned index, unsigned outputs) {
    m_index = index;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < outputs; i++) {
        m_connections.push_back(connection());
    }
    // Set default neuron output
    setOutput(1.0);
}

double neuron::eta = 0.15;    // overall net learning rate, [0.0..1.0]
double neuron::alpha = 0.5;   // momentum, multiplier of last deltaWeight, [0.0..1.0]

// Definition of transfer function method
double neuron::transferFunction(double x) const {
    return tanh(x); // -1 -> 1
}

// Transfer function derivation method
double neuron::transferFunctionDerivative(double x) const {
    return 1 - x*x; // Derivative of tanh
}

// Set output value
void neuron::setOutput(double value) {
    m_output = value;
}

// Forward propagate
void neuron::recalculate(layer &previousLayer) {

    double sum = 0.0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < previousLayer.size(); i++) {
        sum += previousLayer[i].m_output * previousLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_weight;
    }
    setOutput(transferFunction(sum));
}

// Change weights based on target
void neuron::updateWeights(layer &prevLayer) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < prevLayer.size(); i++) {
        double oldDeltaWeight = prevLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_deltaWeight;
        double newDeltaWeight = eta * prevLayer[i].m_output * m_gradient + alpha * oldDeltaWeight;
        prevLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_deltaWeight = newDeltaWeight;
        prevLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_weight += newDeltaWeight; 
    }
}

// Complex math stuff
void neuron::calculateOutputGradients(double target) {
    double delta = target - m_output;
    m_gradient = delta * transferFunctionDerivative(m_output);
}

double neuron::sumDOW(const layer &nextLayer) {
    double sum = 0.0;

    for(unsigned i = 1; i < nextLayer.size(); i++) {
        sum += m_connections[i].m_weight * nextLayer[i].m_gradient;
    }

    return sum;
}

void neuron::calculateHiddenGradients(const layer &nextLayer) {
    double dow = sumDOW(nextLayer);
    m_gradient = dow * neuron::transferFunctionDerivative(m_output);
}
```

Also the line is called here

```
 // Update weights
    for(unsigned layerIndex = m_layers.size() - 1; layerIndex > 0; layerIndex--) {
        layer &currentLayer = m_layers[layerIndex];
        layer &previousLayer = m_layers[layerIndex - 1];

        for(unsigned i = 1; i < currentLayer.size(); i++) {
            currentLayer[i].updateWeights(previousLayer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate further on your problem. Presently, it is unclear how exactly you arrived at this problem, and thus we cannot help you. You might wish to read up on [ask] good questions, to get a better idea of what kinds of questions we expect here on Stack Overflow. Additionally, you may find the page on creating an [mcve] helpful, as your provided example is minimal, but neither complete nor verifiable.

Comment: Hopefully that helps? I'm just very lost since assigning a value to prevLayer[i].m_connections[m_index].m_deltaWeight throws an error, but retrieving a value from it doesn't.

Comment: That's a runtime error (from your C library), not a compilation error. And the code you posted is not a [mcve].

Comment: @Brian *Specifically, commenting out a specific line seems to fix the error* -- Given that line, the error is not "fixed", just masked, since it is more than likely you have corrupted memory.  All you did was move the error from one part of the code to another part of the code.  I suggest you keep that line there, and actually fix the error.

Comment: @Brian `m_connections[m_index]` -- Change all of those to `m_connections.at(m_index)` -- Don't be surprised if you now get a `std::out_of_range` exception being thrown.

Comment: @Brian Also, `for(unsigned layerIndex = m_layers.size() - 1; layerIndex > 0; layerIndex--)` -- what if `m_layers` is empty?  You have a lot of assumptions going on in your code without any explicit checks (like the `m_index` I pointed out earlier, and now this issue).

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor initialize N 'outputs' **m_connections** in the class.

But you have a lot of places calling:

```
m_connections[m_index]
```

What happens if m_index > outputs? Is this possible in your problem?
Try including an assert (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) in the first line of the constructor:

```
assert(index < outputs)
```

You are probably having a bad pointer access somewhere.